# Partition in SQL -clustered and noclustered

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, database-partitioning

I have a requirement to write partition scheme for a table that hold billion records.how will I create a partition script for a table that has both CLUSTERED and NONCLUSTERED index.

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: You need to give far more information - what does your table look like, what is the data, what queries are people running against it etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to deal with partitionning table.

- Just partition the table and not the indexes. The table can be a heap or a clustered one.
- Partition the table and all or some indexes. Which is call
  partitionning alignement.

In such a case, the partition column must be the first columns of the index key.

It is not very common to align table partitioning with indexes so I suggest you do a lot of testing.

Comment: The partition column must be a key column of each unique index; it doesn't need to be the first column.  Non-unique non-clustered indexes can always be partitioned.  SQL Server will add the partition column to the index as needed.

Comment: Yes, I confuse about PK indexes and other indexes. For the PK, you need to add it as a first column of the key, which has frequently no sense...

Comment: It can be a trailing column of a PK too, and for a clustered PK it's often better, as you can _already_ perform efficient range searches on the leading column.